# Calculating the sum 1+(1/2!)+...+(1/n!)

Tags: c, algorithm, factorial

Like the title says, how can I calculate the sum of `n` numbers of the form: `1+(1/2!)+...+(1/n!)`?
I already got the code for the harmonic series:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int v=0,i,ch;
    double x=0.;

    printf("Introduce un número paracalcular la suma: ");

    while(scanf("%d",&v)==0 || v<=0)
    {
        printf("Favor de introducir numeros reales positivos: ");

        while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
            if(ch==EOF)
                return 1;
    }

    for (i=v; i>=1; i--)
        x+=1./i;

    printf("EL valor de la serie es %f\n", x);
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

The question here is: I already got the sum as the fraction, but how can I calculate the variable "i" factorial?

Note: I´m programming in language C, with DEV -C++ 4.9.9.2

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ bigger than around $20,$ just use the mathematical constant $e.$ Below $20,$ it really doesn't matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

Usually by means of a recursive method, one can create a factorial function. Note that:
$$
   n! = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & :  n = 1\\
       n(n-1)! & : n > 1 
     \end{array}
   \right.
 $$

I guess this would mean something like

```
 public int Factorial(int n)       
 {  
      return (n == 1 ? 1 : n * Factorial(n - 1));
 }
```

Comment: For large values of $n$, this should be done via logarithms because the bits stored with integers is not sufficient and is also more susceptible to error. Additionally, to make the code much quicker, for large values of $n$, one can use Stirling's approximation to very high accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

ac = 1;
for (i=n; i>0; i--) ac = ac/i+1;

saves the computation of factorials and avoids rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

No recursion and no factorials.

```
double fraction=1, sum=0;
long i,n;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    sum+=(fraction/=i);
```

Output:

```
n=1
sum=1

n=2
sum=1.5

n=3
sum=1.666666666

n=1073741824
sum=1.71828182845904553488480814849026501178741455078125
```